# Rails server latency is very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

I have a Rails app on Passenger on Nginx on EC2 micro and the server time on an empty page is 3 seconds. Empty page means there's no layout, no JS, no CSS, HTML only consists of header and body tags with a "TEST" text. The controller does nothing.

Here is the server wait time from Chrome console for the empty page:

[image: server wait time]

I also ran ruby-prof on the home page of my app and the total time is 0.2 seconds:

`Total Time: 0.2830359935760498`

Curiously, I created a new Rails app and deployed that instead, and the server wait time shown on Chrome is about ~1.8 seconds, so 1 second faster.

Anyone have any idea what I can do or try? I am using an EC micro instance. Should I move to a box with better network? I feel like this shouldn't be the issue. I've also tried similar testing with Apache instead of Nginx and had similar results. I don't think I have anything weird in Rails.

This is in my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'bower-rails'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'

gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'spring', group: :development
gem 'rake'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
end

group :development do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'byebug'
end

gem 'oauth2'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
gem 'passenger'
gem 'google-adwords-api'
gem 'google-ads-common'
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'angularjs-rails'
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test, :production]

gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.1.2'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'ultrahook'
gem 'rack-reverse-proxy', :require => 'rack/reverse_proxy'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

gem 'city-state'
gem 'readmorejs-rails'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rollbar'

gem 'ruby-prof'
```

Comment: It's hard to say based on this description what might be wrong here. Does a bare, zero add-ons Rails app perform the same way on the same instance type? Does removing some of those dependencies help speed it up?

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to pinpoint so I'm just hoping for suggestions. I mentioned in the post that I created a new, bare Rails app. I created a test page in the bare app with HTML text and the server takes ~2 seconds instead of 3. I did not try removing the gem dependencies yet. I will try that as well. However, an empty app taking 2 seconds is still suspect, so I'm wondering if it could be some Nginx/Passenger/Rails interaction that I'm missing. The installation was pretty trivial and I followed the Passenger website with no issues.

Comment: It could be you're really strapped for memory, so it's worth checking with a tool like `htop` that you're not hitting swap or something awful. It's also worth trying on a slightly larger instance to see if the problem goes away. Normally page loads should be on the 50-100ms range without too much fuss and tuning.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured too, page loads should be in milliseconds. I'll try a bigger box and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried a bigger box (2 CPUs, 4 GB ram) and saw the same ~3 seconds latency.

Comment: You might have considered this already, but location of your server also matters. We had a database server in US location and any query we run on it from India will take ~ 400 ms minimum. But the app server which is located in the same region runs the queries within 3 ms on average.